# Need the answer to this indefinite integral problem.

Tags: calculus

\begin{equation}
  \int\frac{\cos\left(\sqrt{17t}\right)}{\sqrt{17t}}\,\mathrm dt=?
\end{equation}

Need the answer to this problem. Me and my friend been working on it for a while now.

Comment: @StefanHansen: Your edit changed the question. With $\sqrt{17}\,t$ instead of $\sqrt{17t}$, there is no elementary antiderivative...

Comment: @HansLundmark: I'm so sorry, but thanks for noticing and editing it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general: if $\,f(x)\,$ is a derivable function, then

$$\int f'(t)\cos f(t)\,dt=\sin f(t)+C\;\;(\text{differentiate using the chain rule on the RH to prove})$$

In this case,

$$f(t)=\sqrt{17 t}\,\,\,,\,\,f'(t)=\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2\sqrt t}=\frac{17}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{17 t}}\Longrightarrow$$

$$\int\frac{\cos\sqrt{17 t}}{\sqrt{17 t}}dt=\frac{2}{17}\int\left( \frac{17}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{17 t}}\,dt\right)\cos\sqrt{17 t}=\frac{2}{17}\sin\sqrt{17 t}+C$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Try the substitution $u = \sqrt{17t}$.

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $u = \sqrt{17t}$ will change the above integral to $\frac {2}{17}\int \cos  u \,du$ which is now one line answer.